# How to remove Github's Wiki default sidebar

Tags: github, wiki, sidebar

Since a few weeks, Github wikis present a compulsory side bar to the right of wiki pages that take up some space for writing. Example:

[image]

I could not find any button nor instructions on the net to remove this sidebar.

Is there a command or instructions to get it removed somewhere?

Comment: curious if you ever figured this out?

Comment: Not yet. I'd write it back otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now there is not a way to remove the sidebar. I would suggest you make a note to the developers of this issue and they may act upon it. Until then we will just have to deal with the stick sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a definitive answer, but here are a couple tools that might help.

If you're using Chrome or Firefox, you could use the Stylus add-on. It allows you to restyle any webpage by modifying the CSS. You can write your own user styles, but there's several on [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org) for Github. I use [Github Wide](https://userstyles.org/styles/108591/github-wide), which widens the Github interface. That gives me more space for writing.

If that's not enough and you really want to zap the sidebar, a relatively easy way to remove an element from a webpage is to use AdBlock. You can add any element you don't want to see as a custom filter. You might be able to use a combination of that plus your own Stylish user style to tweak the CSS so that the content you want to see fills the now-empty space.

Comment: As an aside, the Github Dark Stylish user style (https://userstyles.org/styles/37035/github-dark) is really excellent if you like a dark theme. The creator updates it often to keep up with Github's UI changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to remove this sidebar.  However, when I am editing a wiki page, if the sidebar is on top of the content, I get a horizontal slider.